# Updating inherited attributes in django model objects

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have troubles updating attributes that are inherited from other tables

```
class AgentCategory(models.Model):
""" Agent Category """
    class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "agentcategories"
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Agent(models.Model):
    agentcategory = models.ManyToManyField(AgentCategory,null=True)
```

How should i go about manually updating agentcategory in Agent model? As of now i am trying out this method, however, it does not work):

```
property_selected.agentcategory = "api/v1/agentcategory/3"
property_selected.save()
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing inherited here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Agent` has `ManyToManyField` relation with `AgentCategory`.

`agentcategory` would contain the list of entries.

you can update its entries by,

```
agent_cats = AgentCategory.objects.filter(...)
property_selected.agentcategory.clear()
property_selected.agentcategory = agent_cats
property_selected.agentcategory.save()
```